# How to calculate an integral of an expression that is determined numerically (in Mathematica)?

Tags: numerics

First of all, I am fairly new to Mathematica and Stackoverflow, so please feel free to give me any advice whatsoever.

I aim to calculate an integral of an expression that has been determined numerically. I will give a simple example:
A solution (dependent on some parameter value a) is derived by

```
Clear[Sol]
Sol[a_] := FindInstance[x^2 == a, x]
```

and results are fine:

```
Sol[4]
```

gives

```
{{x -> 2}}.
```

Obviously, this special example could be solved algebraically, but since the set of equalities and inequalities I want to analyse is much more complicated, FindInstance (and therefore numerical evaluation) is the only option I could think of (the results from Reduce are to complicated to be checked by hand and I don't know how to elegantly get results from Reduce in an automated way; if you have recommendations on how to approach the results from Reduce, please let me know).

I now aim to calculate the integral of the solution given above and try

```
In[3]:= NIntegrate[(x /. Sol[a][[1]]), {a, 1, 4}]

During evaluation of In[3]:= FindInstance::exvar: The system contains a nonconstant expression a independent of variables {x}.

During evaluation of In[3]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {x^2==a} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

During evaluation of In[3]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand x/.x^2==a has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1,4}}.

Out[3]= NIntegrate[x /.Sol[a][[1]], {a, 1, 4}]
```

To mee, it seems like NIntegrate does not "take a value of `a` and plug it into `Sol`, calculate `Sol[a]` and proceed to the next value of a". Therefore I tried to force Mathematica to evaluate `Sol` with numerical values for `a` using commands like Evaluate, With, Block, Module but was unsuccesful (which might be due to poor understanding of these commands).

Thanks for reading and maybe helping me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can define

```
Sol[a_?NumericQ] := FindInstance[x^2 == a, x][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Then

```
Sol[4]
(* 4 *)

NIntegrate[Sol[a], {a, 1, 4}]
(* 4.66667 *)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!